# How to create a mutable copy of a `readonly` record in Ballerina for modifying purposes?"

Tags: ballerina

I'm working on an integration project using Ballerina and leveraging the benefits of the `readonly` record to ensure immutability and concurrency safety. However, I've encountered a scenario where I need to duplicate a `readonly` record to make changes to the duplicated record.

I attempted to use the `record.clone()` method, but it seems that the cloned record remains `readonly` as well.

Is there a recommended approach or workaround to create a mutable copy of a `readonly` record? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`clone()`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0#clone) does not create copies of immutable values.

You could use [`cloneWithType()`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.value/0.0.0#cloneWithType), provided that the target type (and the corresponding type of any part of the structure that is required to be mutable) is not a subtype of `readonly`.

```
import ballerina/io;

type Record record {
    int[] a1;
    int[] & readonly a2;
};

public function main() returns error? {
    Record & readonly immRec = {a1: [1, 2], a2: []};

    Record mutRec = check immRec.cloneWithType();

    io:println(immRec is readonly); // true
    io:println(immRec.a1 is readonly); // true
    io:println(immRec.a2 is readonly); // true

    io:println(<any>mutRec is readonly); // false
    io:println(<any>mutRec.a1 is readonly); // false
    io:println(<any>mutRec.a2 is readonly); // true

    record {
        int[] a1;
        int[] a2; // also mutable
    } mutRec2 = check immRec.cloneWithType();

    io:println(<any>mutRec2 is readonly); // false
    io:println(<any>mutRec2.a1 is readonly); // false
    io:println(<any>mutRec2.a2 is readonly); // false
}
```